# Rows to columns with no specific column headings

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query that returns data which is in rows and I need to change the results so the results are in columns and not rows.  I have done research and found [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server-2008) article which has a dynamic query that can be used but it doesn't seem my situation will be able to use that solution.  That solution seemed to rely on each row having a unique name that could be used as a column name, I don't have that.

My data contains customer records of the visits a customer has had to our facility.  Some customers will only see us once and some will see us many times in the same time span, so we have no way of predicting how many visits per customer we will have in a given time period.  Note ID 10219 has only one visit, 5180 has 3 and there are many for 5199.

```
ID      Task                Visit Date      RF Score    PF Score
10219   Follow Up Visit     12/26/2013      1           6
5180    Initial Visit       6/9/2011        3           9
5180    Follow Up Visit     7/8/2011        3           10
5180    Follow Up Visit     9/2/2011        1           10
5199    Follow Up Visit     9/15/2011       2           7
5199    Follow Up Visit     9/8/2011        5           6
5199    Follow Up Visit     10/27/2011      4           7
5199    Follow Up Visit     10/20/2011      2           4
5199    Follow Up Visit     10/13/2011      4           8
5199    Follow Up Visit     11/17/2011      3           4
5199    Follow Up Visit     11/10/2011      2           5
5199    Follow Up Visit     11/3/2011       3           3
```

With data that is structured like this does anyone know how to convert these rows to columns dynamically even though I don't know how many columns will be needed?

EDIT:  the final result should look like this:

```
    ID          Task1               Visit Date1     RF Score1   PF Score1   Task2               Visit Date2     RF Score2   PF Score2   Task3               Visit Date3     RF Score3   PF Score3   
   5180     Initial Visit           6/9/2011        3           9           Follow Up Visit     7/8/2011        3           10          Follow Up Visit     9/2/2011        1           10
```

Comment: What do you want the final result to look like?

Comment: I edited the OP to include this detail.

Comment: Why do you need to perform this type of PIVOT in SQL? Can't you just return the result to your client ordered by ID, Date and keep going horizontal until you hit a new ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [solution that you link to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server-2008) would work for your case but you have to adjust it slightly because you want to pivot on multiple columns of data.  Since you need to pivot multiple columns, then you first will want to unpivot your `Visit Date`, `Task`, `Rf Score` and `Pf Score` columns into multiple rows, then apply the pivot function.  Besides the process of unpivoting, I would also suggest using a [windowing function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) like `row_number` to generate a unique sequence for each `id` with date.

You will start your query by using the following:

```
select id, task, [visit date], [rf score], [pf score],
  row_number() over(partition by id
                    order by [visit date]) seq
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/39ad9/2). This creates a number that will be used to associate each value in `Visit Date`, `Task`, `Rf Score` and `Pf Score` with the actual number of the visit.

Once you have this row number, then you will want to unpivot your multiple columns into multiple rows of data.  There are several ways to do this including using the unpivot function. But since you are using SQL Server 2008R2, you can use `CROSS APPLY` with `VALUES`:

```
select id, 
  col = col + cast(seq as varchar(10)),
  value
from 
(
  select id, task, [visit date], [rf score], [pf score],
    row_number() over(partition by id
                      order by [visit date]) seq
  from yourtable
) d
cross apply
(
  values
    ('VisitDate', convert(varchar(10), [visit date], 120)),
    ('Task', [task]),
    ('RfScore', cast([rf score] as varchar(10))),
    ('PfScore', cast([pf score] as varchar(10)))
) c (col, value)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/39ad9/12). Your data is now in a format that can easily be pivoted:

```
|    ID |        COL |           VALUE |
|-------|------------|-----------------|
|  5180 | VisitDate1 |      2011-06-09 |
|  5180 |      Task1 |   Initial Visit |
|  5180 |   RfScore1 |               3 |
|  5180 |   PfScore1 |               9 |
|  5180 | VisitDate2 |      2011-07-08 |
|  5180 |      Task2 | Follow Up Visit |
|  5180 |   RfScore2 |               3 |
|  5180 |   PfScore2 |              10 |
```

The code when the PIVOT is added willbe:

```
select id, 
  VisitDate1, Task1, RfScore1, PfScore1,
  VisitDate2, Task2, RfScore2, PfScore2,
  VisitDate3, Task3, RfScore3, PfScore3,
  VisitDate4, Task4, RfScore4, PfScore4,
  VisitDate5, Task5, RfScore5, PfScore5,
  VisitDate6, Task6, RfScore6, PfScore6
from
(
  select id, 
    col = col + cast(seq as varchar(10)),
    value
  from 
  (
    select id, task, [visit date], [rf score], [pf score],
      row_number() over(partition by id
                        order by [visit date]) seq
    from yourtable
  ) d
  cross apply
  (
    values
      ('VisitDate', convert(varchar(10), [visit date], 120)),
      ('Task', [task]),
      ('RfScore', cast([rf score] as varchar(10))),
      ('PfScore', cast([pf score] as varchar(10)))
  ) c (col, value)
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in (VisitDate1, Task1, RfScore1, PfScore1,
              VisitDate2, Task2, RfScore2, PfScore2,
              VisitDate3, Task3, RfScore3, PfScore3,
              VisitDate4, Task4, RfScore4, PfScore4,
              VisitDate5, Task5, RfScore5, PfScore5,
              VisitDate6, Task6, RfScore6, PfScore6)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/39ad9/13).

The above works great if you have a limited number of value, but if they are unknown then you will need to use dynamic SQL and the code above will be converted to:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(col + cast(seq as varchar(10))) 
                    from
                    (
                      select row_number() over(partition by id
                                                order by [visit date]) seq
                      from yourtable
                    ) d
                    cross apply
                    (
                      select 'VisitDate', 1 union all
                      select 'Task', 2 union all
                      select 'RfScore', 3 union all
                      select 'PfScore', 4
                    ) c (col, so)
                    group by seq, col, so
                    order by seq, so
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'select id,  ' + @cols + ' 
            from
            (
              select id, 
                col = col + cast(seq as varchar(10)),
                value
              from
              (
                select id, task, [visit date], [rf score], [pf score],
                  row_number() over(partition by id
                                    order by [visit date]) seq
                from yourtable
              ) d
              cross apply
              (
                values
                  (''VisitDate'', convert(varchar(10), [visit date], 120)),
                  (''Task'', task),
                  (''RfScore'', cast([rf score] as varchar(10))),
                  (''PfScore'', cast([pf score] as varchar(10)))
              ) c (col, value)
            ) s
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/39ad9/15).  Both versions give a result:

```
|    ID | VISITDATE1 |           TASK1 | RFSCORE1 | PFSCORE1 | VISITDATE2 |           TASK2 | RFSCORE2 | PFSCORE2 | VISITDATE3 |           TASK3 | RFSCORE3 | PFSCORE3 | VISITDATE4 |           TASK4 | RFSCORE4 | PFSCORE4 | VISITDATE5 |           TASK5 | RFSCORE5 | PFSCORE5 | VISITDATE6 |           TASK6 | RFSCORE6 | PFSCORE6 | VISITDATE7 |           TASK7 | RFSCORE7 | PFSCORE7 | VISITDATE8 |           TASK8 | RFSCORE8 | PFSCORE8 |
|-------|------------|-----------------|----------|----------|------------|-----------------|----------|----------|------------|-----------------|----------|----------|------------|-----------------|----------|----------|------------|-----------------|----------|----------|------------|-----------------|----------|----------|------------|-----------------|----------|----------|------------|-----------------|----------|----------|
|  5180 | 2011-06-09 |   Initial Visit |        3 |        9 | 2011-07-08 | Follow Up Visit |        3 |       10 | 2011-09-02 | Follow Up Visit |        1 |       10 |     (null) |          (null) |   (null) |   (null) |     (null) |          (null) |   (null) |   (null) |     (null) |          (null) |   (null) |   (null) |     (null) |          (null) |   (null) |   (null) |     (null) |          (null) |   (null) |   (null) |
|  5199 | 2011-09-08 | Follow Up Visit |        5 |        6 | 2011-09-15 | Follow Up Visit |        2 |        7 | 2011-10-13 | Follow Up Visit |        4 |        8 | 2011-10-20 | Follow Up Visit |        2 |        4 | 2011-10-27 | Follow Up Visit |        4 |        7 | 2011-11-03 | Follow Up Visit |        3 |        3 | 2011-11-10 | Follow Up Visit |        2 |        5 | 2011-11-17 | Follow Up Visit |        3 |        4 |
| 10219 | 2013-12-26 | Follow Up Visit |        1 |        6 |     (null) |          (null) |   (null) |   (null) |     (null) |          (null) |   (null) |   (null) |     (null) |          (null) |   (null) |   (null) |     (null) |          (null) |   (null) |   (null) |     (null) |          (null) |   (null) |   (null) |     (null) |          (null) |   (null) |   (null) |     (null) |          (null) |   (null) |   (null) |
```